# GRUB going straight to console after new Arch install

Tags: arch-linux, grub2

I am installing arch linux on a VirtualBox machine and I am having trouble getting GRUB configured. I have followed the steps in tutorials and from other posts, but no matter what, GRUB always boots into a console, and I can only get into an OS of any kind through the installation media. I have looked at multiple different tutorials on different new VMs, but it hasn't worked.


Currently I have /dev/sda1 as my /mnt, /dev/sda2 as my swap space, and /dev/sda5 as /mnt/home. I don't know if it will help, but I have also been running into issues with other things, such as enabling dhcpcd (although it may have something to do with the fact that my network adapter is kind of messed up because VirtualBox) but I can still connect to the internet.


If you have any idea how to help, I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? And then is Arch installed in UEFI or BIOS(CSM) boot mode? Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Did you run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` after installing grub?

Comment: I did make the config, but I just figured out (thanks to a reddit post by someone with the same problem) that most tutorials don't point out that you need to install linux and linux-firmware when you bootstrap the system. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/e3kwes/cant_get_arch_to_boot_new_install/) I found out that most tutorials don't tell you that while you are bootstrapping the system, you need to install `linux` and `linux-firmware` as well as `base`.
When you are bootstrapping the system run this:

```
pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware
```

I was trying to find an answer for a while, so I hope anyone with the same problem can find this faster than I could!

Comment: This is one of the very first things listed on the Arch Wiki installation guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Installation

Comment: @ajgringo619 Thank you for the response! I am new to arch and I just wanted to make sure that people in my situation who were following a guide instead of the wiki (because the wiki isn’t the most straightforward place for new people) would be able to find this answer.